# How prevent the text caret/cursor jumping to the end in a text box on an incorrect entry using an angularjs directive?

Tags: javascript, string, dom-events

I have a problem. I want to create a directive in AngularJS that restricts the input to certain characters only. This I can achieve. The issue is fine when I am typing at the end of a string, but if I use my mouse to change the text cursor/caret position [that flashing horizontal line] and type an incorrect character, **the text cursor/caret jumps to the end of the string**! Is there any way to STOP this?

In other words, prevent the event from happening and keeping my text cursor/caret in the same position? **I am trying to ensure that in the text box the user can only type at most one space, and prevent multiple.** Upon hitting multiple the text cursor does not move and nothing happens.

E.g.

```
 "a b c" is valid. "a b c " is valid
 "abc" is valid.
 "a[space][space]b"  is not valid, note the [space] = ' '.
```

You can try it yourself on this example but it's with digits:
https://embed.plnkr.co/hihevOKDtXSVmVqP0KBp/

Here's an example with digits if that's easier:

digitsOnly I type: "12345|" where the horizontal line is the text caret

then I type from this position something incorrect like 'a' "123|45" the text cursor/caret jumps to the end or back to here "12345|". I do not want that. I want the text cursor to still be between 3 and 4.

Comment: maybe [selectionStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Property/selectionStart) can help you?

Comment: Once you get an event, save your string. on change of the string, split your string and compare the two strings

Comment: Do not try to prevent the user from entering certain characters. The user will think their keyboard is broken and become very frustrated. Instead, check the input when the user tries to submit the form. Or use `pattern` or `type` or other HTML5 input validation features.

Comment: @VamshiGudipati I understand that idea but then I end up using $setViewValue and then I $render it. The $render function still moves the text cursor to the end!

Comment: @torazaburo that's just the requirement. I do agree with you! Also would that prevent multiple spaces?

Comment: It would prevent multiple consecutive spaces if you wrote the pattern to as to prevent multiple spaces.

Comment: @torazaburo but that still doesn't answer the specific question about preventing the text cursor from jumping to the end of the string if you type something incorrect.